# Deploy JEE application from Netbeans to Payara docker image

Tags: docker, netbeans, payara

I'm currently running a traditional development setup on my local machine:

db: mariadb

app server: payara

ide: netbeans

plus some node docker containers.

I'm using the Payara plugin in NetBeans to control Payara and deploy my JEE aps directly to the app server. It works like a charm.

But I would like to run payara and mariadb in docker containers. I have created my docker images and I can start the db as well as the payara app server without any problems. It works.

I can manually deploy my war file in payara and run the corresponding web app. No problems here. I can ping the db from the dockerized app server.

But the last step in the process is impossible for me to grasp. How do I deploy the web app directly from NetBeans to my Payara docker container.

I can't find any documentation on that. When I add a server to NetBeans I can chose payara server and select remote domain. I have an opportunity to click 'docker volume' but I don't know what to enter in 'Host Path' and 'Container Path'.

Is it possble at all to control Payara running in a docker container the same way as when running Payara as a normal app server?

Kim

Answer (score 0):

At runtime of the Payara container, there must be a deployments folder where the war file gets copied to.

For the containerized Payara you can achieve that in two ways:

### Backe the application in at container build time

Build your war file. Place it besides a Dockerfile. In the Dockerfile have some line like

```
ADD warfilename.war /payara/deployments
```

Perform a `docker build` and the container will have the application builtin.
I am assuming your warfile's name is 'warfilename.war' and needs to be visible inside the container in the `/payara/deployments` folder.

### Mount the directory hosting the application at container run time

Suppose you have the vanilla Payara container, without your application.
Then run it like

```
docker run --name payara -v warfilenamedirectory:/payara/deployments payara:latest
```

I am assuming your warfile is contained in a directory `warfilenamedirectory` and needs to be visible inside the container at `/payara/deployments`.